# Running pure Groovy code in a step inside a Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following stages in my `test.groocy` pipeline:

```
stages {
  stage('Test') {
    steps {
       env.SOME_VAR = new File("settings.gradle")
         .readLines()
         .findAll { someLogic }
         .collect { it =~ /.*'(.*)'/ }
       echo "got: ${SOME_VAR}"
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm getting:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: settings.gradle (No such file or directory)
```

If I change the code to:

```
stages {
  stage('Test') {
    steps {
       sh(returnStdout: true,
       script: '''#!/bin/bash
                  cat settings.gradle''')
    }
  }
}
```

I can see the file's content.

1. Why isn't it recognizing the file in the first snippet, but does recognize it in the second one?
2. Is there a way to make the upper snippet works as expected in Jenkins?

Comment: First guess would be because the `File` class only works correctly for paths on the Jenkins master, and not the build agents. Is this file on the master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sh`, as other Jenkins steps, started in current workspace directory.

So, you could replace native java/groovy `new File` with Jenkins `readFile` and the rest of your code should work.

```
readFile("settings.gradle").readLines()...
```

Or specify the full path for `new File`

```
new File("${WORKSPACE}/settings.gradle").readLines()...
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it.

Comment: groovy (actually java) works in global jenkins agent environment. and i believe current dir for jenkins would be jenkins/bin (or smth like this). you can check it by: `println( new File(".").getAbsolutePath() )`. for all jobs the value would be the same.

Comment: That's very helpful. Thanks for your answer.